# fsck on disk while Linux machine is up with runlevel N 5

Tags: redhat, hard-drive, kernel, fsck

we have linux machine , and we did the disk repair as the following

```
umount /grid/sde
fsck.ext4 /dev/sde
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/sde: clean, 103867/1310720 files, 4725204/5242880 blocks
this not was from single user mode , the machine was up with multi user mode
```

runlevel
N 5
so the question is

is it ok to run fsck from runlevel N 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to run fsck in runlevel 5 as long as you don't need the data on disc. The filesystem has to unmounted for fsck to run. If the filesystem is mounted you aren't able to run fsck.

After fsck you can mount the filesystem again (assuming no errors were found) and continue to use it.